# CSS: min-height does not work

Tags: css, height, html

Whenever I add the min0height property to the DIVs to make them 100%, it doesn't work. I have added them to all of the DIVs, including height: 100%; and min-height: 100%; but nothing works. What would I do to make it extend all the way? It just cuts off the background of the sidebar and the background color of the content area.

[image]

(Forgot to label a part. The content area with the white background is .col1)

**CSS:**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

img {
    border-style: none;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}
body {
    background-color:#000;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;           /* This removes the border around the viewport in old versions of IE */
    width:100%;
}
.sidebar {
    background-image:url(../images/sidebar/background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    font: 12px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    color: #666;
    z-index:1;
}
.menu {
    background-image:url(../images/top_menu/background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:25px;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    z-index:5;
    background-color:#000;
}
.bottom_menu {
    background-image:url(../images/bottom_menu/background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:20px;
    z-index:2;
    font: 12px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
}
.colmask {
    position:relative;      /* This fixes the IE7 overflow hidden bug and stops the layout jumping out of place */
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%; /* width of whole page */
    overflow:hidden;    /* This chops off any overhanging divs */
}
.sidebar .colright {
    float:left;
    width:200%;
    position:relative;
    left:225px;
    background:#fff;
}
.sidebar .col1wrap {
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    position:relative;
    right:225px;
}
.sidebar .col1 {
    margin:30px 15px 0 225px; /* TOP / UNKNOWN / UNKNOWN / RIGHT */
    position:relative;
    right:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.sidebar .col2 {
    float:left;
    width:225px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-left:5px;
    right:225px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="menu">Header Content</div>
<div class="colmask sidebar">
    <div class="colright">
      <div class="col1wrap">
            <div class="col1" id="contentDIV">
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            Sidebar Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom_menu">Footer Content</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.
It was the container div right after the body tag. Even with height CSS, it created problems. I removed it and changed a script I had from rendering in that div to the document.body and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make your content and sidebar stretch the entire height of the page, then no amount of setting a height is really going to help. If you use 100%, your going to push your fotter off the bottom of the page so you have to scroll to see it. There is a single method that I know of that will allow you to have a full-height body with a footer: Sticky Footer

Check the following site for details: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Another trick you will probably need. It is near impossible to get two columns to have equal height and support all browsers. The simplest way to get your gray column to the left and white center body to stretch all the way to the footer is to use a 1-pixel hight image that has gray and white in the proper proportions, which is background-repeated along the y axis.

Another great site for CSS knowledge is [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/).

Comment: The only thing I don't get is that the footer and header are just floating divs. It shouldn't affect the other divs for the sidebar and content. Maybe I'm wrong, but I figured the header and footer were fine as they were.

Comment: There really isn't anything wrong with your header and footer the way they are......if you don't care about having a full-height content area. That sticky footer technique is the ONLY technique I know of to get a full-height content area with a footer...and I've done a TON of CSS over the many, many years I've used it (since the mid 1990's.)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to get a consistant layout using floats and positioning on the same elements. In particular float and position:fixed (or absolute) are incompatible and each browser handles the situation differently.

IE6 does not support position:fixed at all and treats it as position:static (the default - no positioning at all).

Comment: This is going to be a web based application and unfortunately will not support IE6 at all. Too much stuff for it to handle. I realize thats a large amount of users, but how hard is it for them to get Firefox or Chrome? Takes less than 3 minutes.