# Why doesn't the height of a container element increase if it contains floated elements?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I would like to ask how height and float work. I have an outer div and an inner div that has content in it. Its height may vary depending on the content of the inner div but it seems that my inner div will overflow its outside div. What would be the proper way to do it?

```html
 <html>
    <body>
        <div style="margin:0 auto;width: 960px; min-height: 100px; background-color:orange">
         <div style="width:500px; height:200px; background-color:black; float:right"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: min-height does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958888/css-min-height-does-not-work) or [CSS: Div height problem on float set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009931/css-div-height-problem-on-float-set?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [floating stuff within a div, floats outside of div. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2062258/1529630)

Answer (score 630, accepted):

The floated elements do not add to the height of the container element, and hence if you don't clear them, container height won't increase...

I'll show you visually:

[image]

[image]

[image]

More Explanation:

```
<div>
  <div style="float: left;"></div>
  <div style="width: 15px;"></div> <!-- This will shift 
                                        besides the top div. Why? Because of the top div 
                                        is floated left, making the 
                                        rest of the space blank -->

  <div style="clear: both;"></div> 
  <!-- Now in order to prevent the next div from floating beside the top ones, 
       we use `clear: both;`. This is like a wall, so now none of the div's 
       will be floated after this point. The container height will now also include the 
       height of these floated divs -->
  <div></div>
</div>
```

You can also add `overflow: hidden;` on container elements, but I would suggest you use `clear: both;` instead.

Also if you might like to self-clear an element you can use

```
.self_clear:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

---

## How Does CSS Float Work?

### What is float exactly and what does it do?

- The `float` property is misunderstood by most beginners. Well, what exactly does `float` do? Initially, the `float` property was introduced to flow text around images, which are floated `left` or `right`. [Here's another explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#comment26828942_12871734) by @Madara Uchicha.

  So, is it wrong to use the `float` property for placing boxes side by side? The answer is **no**; there is no problem if you use the `float` property in order to set boxes side by side.
- Floating an `inline` or `block` level element will make the element behave like an `inline-block` element.

  [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/W3GJm/)
- If you float an element `left` or `right`, the `width` of the element will be limited to the content it holds, unless `width` is defined explicitly ...
- You cannot `float` an element `center`. This is the biggest issue I've always seen with beginners, using <s>`float: center;`</s>, which is not a valid value for the `float` property. `float` is generally used to `float`/move content to the very *left* or to the very *right*. There are only *four* valid values for `float` property i.e `left`, `right`, `none` (default) and `inherit`.
- Parent element collapses, when it contains floated child elements, in order to prevent this, we use `clear: both;` property, to clear the floated elements on both the sides, which will prevent the collapsing of the parent element. For more information, you can refer my another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12871734/1542290).
- **(Important)** Think of it where we have a stack of various elements. When we use `float: left;` or `float: right;` the element moves above the stack by one. Hence the elements in the normal document flow will hide behind the floated elements because it is on stack level above the normal floated elements. **(Please don't relate this to `z-index` as that is completely different.)**

---

Taking a case as an example to explain how CSS floats work, assuming we need a simple 2 column layout with a header, footer, and 2 columns, so here is what the blueprint looks like...

[image]

In the above example, we will be floating only the red boxes, either you can `float` both to the `left`, or you can `float` on to `left`, and another to `right` as well, depends on the layout, if it's 3 columns, you may `float` 2 columns to `left` where another one to the `right` so depends, though in this example, we have a simplified 2 column layout so will `float` one to `left` and the other to the `right`.

Markup and styles for creating the layout explained further down...

```
<div class="main_wrap">
    <header>Header</header>
    <div class="wrapper clear">
        <div class="floated_left">
            This<br />
            is<br />
            just<br />
            a<br />
            left<br />
            floated<br />
            column<br />
        </div>
        <div class="floated_right">
            This<br />
            is<br />
            just<br />
            a<br />
            right<br />
            floated<br />
            column<br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>

* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;       /* Just for demo purpose */
    -webkkit-box-sizing: border-box;   /* Just for demo purpose */
    box-sizing: border-box;            /* Just for demo purpose */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main_wrap {
    margin: 20px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 520px;
}

header, footer {
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid silver;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
    border: 3px solid green;
}

.floated_left {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.floated_right {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.clear:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

Let's go step by step with the layout and see how float works..

First of all, we use the main wrapper element, you can just assume that it's your viewport, then we use `header` and assign a `height` of `50px` so nothing fancy there. It's just a normal non floated block level element which will take up `100%` horizontal space unless it's floated or we assign `inline-block` to it.

The first valid value for `float` is `left` so in our example, we use `float: left;` for `.floated_left`, so we intend to float a block to the `left` of our container element.

[Column floated to the left](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmk9s/)

And yes, if you see, the parent element, which is `.wrapper` is collapsed, the one you see with a green border didn't expand, but it should right? Will come back to that in a while, for now, we have got a column floated to `left`.

Coming to the second column, lets it `float` this one to the `right`

[Another column floated to the right](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmk9s/1/)

Here, we have a `300px` wide column which we `float` to the `right`, which will sit beside the first column as it's floated to the `left`, and since it's floated to the `left`, it created empty gutter to the `right`, and since there was ample of space on the `right`, our `right` floated element sat perfectly beside the `left` one.

Still, the parent element is collapsed, well, let's fix that now. There are many ways to prevent the parent element from getting collapsed.

- Add an empty block level element and use `clear: both;` before the parent element ends, which holds floated elements, now this one is a cheap solution to `clear` your floating elements which will do the job for you but, I would recommend not to use this.

Add, `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` before the `.wrapper` `div` ends, like

```
<div class="wrapper clear">
    <!-- Floated columns -->
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmk9s/2/)

Well, that fixes very well, no collapsed parent anymore, but it adds unnecessary markup to the DOM, so some suggest, to use `overflow: hidden;` on the parent element holding floated child elements which work as intended.

Use `overflow: hidden;` on `.wrapper`

```
.wrapper {
    border: 3px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmk9s/3/)

That saves us an element every time we need to `clear` `float` but as I tested various cases with this, it failed in one particular one, which uses `box-shadow` on the child elements.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmk9s/4/) (Can't see the shadow on all 4 sides, `overflow: hidden;` causes this issue)

So what now? Save an element, no `overflow: hidden;` so go for a clear fix hack, use the below snippet in your CSS, and just as you use `overflow: hidden;` for the parent element, call the `class` below on the parent element to self-clear.

```
.clear:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

<div class="wrapper clear">
    <!-- Floated Elements -->
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmk9s/5/)

Here, shadow works as intended, also, it self-clears the parent element which prevents to collapse.

And lastly, we use footer after we `clear` the floated elements.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmk9s/6/)

---

When is `float: none;` used anyways, as it is the default, so any use to declare `float: none;`?

Well, it depends, if you are going for a responsive design, you will use this value a lot of times, when you want your floated elements to render one below another at a certain resolution. For that `float: none;` property plays an important role there.

---

Few real-world examples of how `float` is useful.

- The first example we already saw is to create one or more than one column layouts.
- Using `img` floated inside `p` which will enable our content to flow around.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xZPX7/) (Without floating `img`)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/xZPX7/1/) (`img` floated to the `left`)

- Using `float` for creating horizontal menu - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xZPX7/2/)

---

#### Float second element as well, or use `margin`

Last but not the least, I want to explain this particular case where you `float` only single element to the `left` but you do not `float` the other, so what happens?

Suppose if we remove `float: right;` from our `.floated_right` `class`, the `div` will be rendered from extreme `left` as it isn't floated.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmk9s/7/)

So in this case, either you can [`float` the to the `left` as well](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmk9s/8/)

OR

You can [use `margin-left` which will be equal to the size of the left floated column i.e `200px` wide](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmk9s/9/).

Comment: The fact that floats do not contribute to the height of a block-level parent is explicitly stated here in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#normal-block The reason why adding a clearfix works is because 1) the clearfix is (usually) in the normal flow 2) clearing floats requires that the clearfix be placed at the very bottom of the floats 3) the container has to be stretched to contain that clearfix.

Comment: @BoltClock it would be better if you rollback the title edit as will severely impact the seo for the users who find how float works.. you can write those terms on google and check.. else this canonical answer is of no use if people are not able to find what they are looking for.

Comment: "How does CSS float work?" is an extremely broad title, and it's also misleading people into [voting to close just any float question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28724993) as a dupe of this one. The question here only covers one aspect: containers wrapping (or not wrapping) floats.

Comment: @BoltClock Anyways the technicality remains the same as explained in `clear: both;`, but it's fine if you feel the edit justifies so lets keep that way

Comment: brilliant answer.       "Floating any element to left or right, the width of the element will be limited to the content it holds, unless width is defined explicitly" - i observed the same thing and was just looking for this to be confirmed. Thank you

Comment: <div style="clear: both;"></div> is more of a hack in this case. The actual div has no semantical meaning. It is basically html tag for styling.

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` worked better for my use because I have some unpredictable float attributes that are dynamically changed by js. Helpful solution.

Answer (score 41):

You need to add `overflow:auto` to your parent div for it to encompass the inner floated div:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;width: 960px; min-height: 100px; background-color:orange;overflow:auto">
    <div style="width:500px; height:200px; background-color:black; float:right">
    </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6Bu8d/)**

Comment: this is not a solution, you are hidding the content wich go out of the boundaries from the outside div.

Comment: @AlejandroRuizArias - Exactly how is anything being hidden?

Comment: In this example nothing, but if you introduce enough content in the inner div yes.

Comment: This does not do what the OP was looking for: Forked http://jsfiddle.net/h0ceb5ra/

Comment: Awesome. The one attribute solution I was looking for, if everything else was that easy, there would be no need for shrinks.

Answer (score 12):

You are encountering the float bug (though I'm not sure if it's technically a bug due to how many browsers exhibit this behaviour).  Here is what is happening:

Under normal circumstances, assuming that no explicit height has been set, a block level element such as a div will set its height based on its content.  The bottom of the parent div will extend beyond the last element.  Unfortunately, floating an element stops the parent from taking the floated element into account when determining its height.  This means that if your last element is floated, it will not "stretch" the parent in the same way a normal element would.

**Clearing**

There are two common ways to fix this.  The first is to add a "clearing" element; that is, another element below the floated one that will force the parent to stretch.  So add the following html as the last child:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

It shouldn't be visible, and by using clear:both, you make sure that it won't sit next to the floated element, but after it.

**Overflow:**

The second method, which is preferred by most people (I think) is to change the CSS of the parent element so that the overflow is anything but "visible".  So setting the overflow to "hidden" will force the parent to stretch beyond the bottom of the floated child.  This is only true if you haven't set a height on the parent, of course.

Like I said, the second method is preferred as it doesn't require you to go and add semantically meaningless elements to your markup, but there are times when you need the `overflow` to be visible, in which case adding a clearing element is more than acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

Its because of the float of the div. Add `overflow: hidden` on the outside element.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; margin:0 auto;width: 960px; min-height: 100px; background-color:orange;">
    <div style="width:500px; height:200px; background-color:black; float:right">
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LqDJw/)

Answer (score 3):

You confuse how browsers renders the elements when there are floating elements. If one block element is floating (your inner div in your case), other block elements will ignore it because browser removes floating elements from the normal flow of the web page. Then, because the floated div has been removed from the normal flow, the outside div is filled in, like the inner div isn't there. However, inline elements (images, links, text, blackquotes) will respect the boundaries of the floating element. If you introduce text in the outside div, the text will place arround de inner div.

In other words, block elements (headers, paragraphs, divs, etc) ignore floating elements and fill in, and inline elements (images, links, text, etc) respect boundaries of floating elements.

[An fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/aleruar/GK4zD/)

```
<body>
    <div style="float:right; background-color:blue;width:200px;min-height:400px;margin-right:20px">
           floating element
    </div>
    <h1 style="background-color:red;"> this is a big header</h1>
    <p style="background-color:green"> this is a parragraph with text and a big image. The text places arrounds the floating element. Because of the image is wider than space between paragrah and floating element places down the floating element. Try to make wider the viewport and see what happens :D
        <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_nKxzQGcCLtQ/TBYPAJ6xM4I/AAAAAAAAAC8/lG6XemOXosU/s1600/css.png">
     </p>
```

Comment: Do not highlight the text and share fiddle links, post codes in your answer from next time, cuz if fiddle link is dead, future user's won't get any help here and your answer will have no meaning

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
.parent_div{
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use overflow property to the container div if you don't have any div to show over the container eg:

```
<div class="cointainer">
    <div class="one">Content One</div>
    <div class="two">Content Two</div>
</div>
```

Here is the following css:

```
.container{
    width:100%;/* As per your requirment */
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.one{
    width:200px;/* As per your requirment */
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}

.two{
    width:200px;/* As per your requirment */
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
```

-----------------------OR------------------------------

```
    <div class="cointainer">
        <div class="one">Content One</div>
        <div class="two">Content Two</div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is the following css:

```
    .container{
        width:100%;/* As per your requirment */
        height:auto;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .one{
        width:200px;/* As per your requirment */
        height:auto;
        float:left;
    }

    .two{
        width:200px;/* As per your requirment */
        height:auto;
        float:left;
    }
    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after{
        display: table;
        content: " ";
    }
    .clearfix:after{
        clear: both;
    }
```