# CSS div floats below parent div when I float:left

Tags: html, css, css-float

The div "**headerlinks**" floats through the the bottom left of the div "**header**"
but if I reload the page the div is in the correct place. I don't know if its my css or a browser bug. I am using `Chrome 29.0.1547.62 (Official Build 219432) Mac OS X`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b8B4W/)

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="/">
    <img src="blackdiamondcraft.com/title.png" alt="Home"></a>
    <div id="headerlinks">
        <a class="boxlink" href="/nothing">Nothing</a> 
        <a class="boxlink" href="/nothing">Nothing</a>
        <a class="boxlink" href="/nothing">Nothing</a> 
        <a class="boxlink" href="/nothing">Nothing</a> 
        <a class="boxlink" href="/nothing">Nothing</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.boxlink {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border: solid #999999 1px;
    padding: 5px;
}
#header {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d2ff52 0%, #91e842 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d2ff52), color-stop(100%,#91e842));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d2ff52 0%,#91e842 100%);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: solid 4px black;
    margin: 4px;
}
#headerlinks{
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #66ffcc;
    position: inherit;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: solid #000 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear your floats, use `overflow: hidden;` on parent element

```
#header {
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d2ff52 0%, #91e842 100%);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d2ff52), color-                     stop(100%,#91e842));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d2ff52 0%,#91e842 100%);
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 3px;
   border: solid 4px black;
   margin: 4px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cmAKx/)

---

Even a better way to do is use a self clearing parent element using the below snippet

```
.clear:after {
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    content: "";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cmAKx/1/)

---

Explanation : When you float your elements to the left or right, the parent element collapses as it has no idea that whats the `height` of your parent element, inorder to fix that, you need to clear floats with the above solutions I provided, apart from this, you can also use `clear: both;`, for a better understanding, you can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12871734/1542290) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it).

Comment: The div "header" gets its height from an image [link] (http://blackdiamondcraft.com/title.png) so is clear:both; required?

Comment: @AW3SOMELOLwUT Didn't got you

Comment: The div gets its width from an image, does #header need clear:both; if there is an image that is higher than the hight of #headerlinks

Comment: @AW3SOMELOLwUT yes, read my answers, it is a good practice to clear your floating elements, I've provided you 2 links which are related to this