# Selection of an element affected by placement of divs

Tags: html

```
      <span class="a" dojoAttachPoint="apoint"></span>  
      <span class="b"   dojoAttachPoint="bpoint">hyperlinked msg</span>
      <span class="c" dojoAttachPoint="cpoint"></span>
      <div>Hello</div>
```

css:

```
      .a, .b, .c{
            float:left
      }
```

Now when i am selecting the hyperlinked message, it is also selecting the next div's text 'Hello'.To avoid this problem I changed the code to

```
      <div>Hello</div>
      <span class="a" dojoAttachPoint="apoint"></span>  
      <span class="b"   dojoAttachPoint="bpoint">hyperlinked msg</span>
      <span class="c" dojoAttachPoint="cpoint"></span>
```

And this solved the problem.Can anyone please provide an explanantion as to how this problem got solved?

Comment: You need to clear your floats, read my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16568504/1542290)

Answer (score 0):

you forget your flux :

```
<span class="a" dojoAttachPoint="apoint"></span>  
<span class="b"   dojoAttachPoint="bpoint">hyperlinked msg</span>
<span class="c" dojoAttachPoint="cpoint"></span>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div>Hello</div>
```

CSS

```
.a, .b, .c{
            float:left
      }
```

[faq clear](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)

Comment: it has not solved the issue..its still selecting Hello..moreover by doing so 'Hello' comes to next line..which is not required

Comment: Plz, past a Codepen, i don't see your problem.