# Bizarre tag positioning

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have placed two divs inside a container tag. The container simply centers and fixes the content.

I want to have space at the bottom of the site, between `home-segment` and the bottom of the browser. For some reason however, the `bottom-spacer` floats above `home-segment`. How can I move it down below `home-segment`?

```
    <div class="container">

    // Content

    <div class="home-segment">
        <div class="col w33 col-first">
            <h2>A title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col w33">
            <h2>Hey there.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col w33 col-last">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom-spacer"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Home Page Columns */

.home-segment { width: 830px; float: left; }
.col-first { margin-left: 0 !important; }
.col.w33 { width: 220px; min-height: 200px; max-height: 200px; border: 1px solid #D9D4D4; background: #fff; margin-right: 15px; }
.col.w33 h2 { font-size: 18px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
.col-last { margin-right: 0 !important; }
.col { display: block; float: left; position: relative; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; }

.bottom-spacer { padding-bottom: 25px; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is shifting to the [top](http://jsfiddle.net/dKC6F/1/) as you are not clearing your floated elements

Add `clear: both;` to `.bottom-spacer`

```
.bottom-spacer { clear: both;padding-bottom: 25px; background: #f00;}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dKC6F/)

---

For detailed explanation for the behavior, you can refer my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504)

Comment: I figured it out, forgot about `clear: both`. Thanks!