# li element won't properly wrap within its container

Tags: html, css

I want to make the horizontal boxes with the size of 200 x 200 pixel each.  I decide to use the `ul li`. and you guys know well that I must apply the `float:left` attribute to the `li` tag to make it horizontal.

My problem is that when I apply the `float:left` to the `li` element, all content in `li` completely breaks its container. I noticed this because I append the border style to the main container and all the content is in the new line below the main container.

Here is my code

HTML :

```
<div class="content-box">
   <h3 class="box-header">Recent Files</h3>
   <ul class="horizontal-content">
       <li>
          <div class="filebox">
          </div>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

and the css :

```
.content-box {
   position:relative;
   width:800px;
   border:1px solid #dadada;
   margin-left:10px;
   padding:10px;
}

ul.horizontal-content {
    list-style:none outside none;
}

ul.horizontal-content > li {
float:left;
display:block;
padding:10px;
}

.filebox {
position:relative;
padding:15px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid #dadada;
background-color:#ecf0f1;
}
```

Now you see all of my code, please help me figure out what I have done wrong.

Comment: can you recreate the problem in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HPfPG/1/

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504

Comment: @Praveen Jeganathan, you could also indent the code.

Comment: Nota :  apply the float:left attribute to the li tag to make it horizontal **is not mandatory**, try display:inline-block

Comment: Well there's a war here between `float` and `inline-block` so if you are confused than give some time and read [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/give-floats-the-flick-in-css-layouts/)

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need `float:left` to make it horizontal. Just add `display:inline-block` and remove `float`

```
ul.horizontal-content > li {
  padding:10px;
  background:grey;
  display:inline-block
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aweMOke/2/)**

Comment: Why make it `inline-block`, just `clear` the `float` http://jsfiddle.net/HPfPG/2/

Comment: why use float:left when it is really not necessary.. OP is using float to make li horizontal, so in that case inline is the best way.

Comment: Obviously it will, that's why I wrote there :)

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
ul.horizontal-content {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: That's really close to what I want but I just want all four boxes to be wrapped in the container with the border. Do u know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

here use `overflow:auto` and here is link of demo [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MNtpt/)

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying many of the solutions but they won't solve. I will create the JSfiddle for you guys to see what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Okay, all problems are solved with clear:both