# Outer div not expaning in height with innner divs

Tags: html, css

In the following code the div content-container is not expanding  in its height as increase in the height of the divs inside it. I want to make its height auto increment with the increase in height of inner divs

This id my css code

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background:#f7f7f7;
}

b{font-size: 110%;}
em{color: red;}

#maincontainer{
    width: 1000px; /*Width of main container*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*Center container on page*/
}

#topsection{
    background: #f0f0f0;
    height: 90px; /*Height of top section*/
}

#topsection h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#content-container{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
    margin-top:-22px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    height:auto;
}

#contentwrapper{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;    
}

#contentcolumn{
    margin-right: 310px; /*Set right margin to RightColumnWidth*/
    background:none;
    padding:15px;
    clear:both;

}

#rightcolumn{
    float: left;
    width: 310px; /*Width of right column*/
    margin-left: -311px; /*Set left margin to -(RightColumnWidth) */
    background: none;
    padding-top:20px;
    margin-top:1px;
    border-left:1px solid #222222;

}

#rightcolumn h2{
    font:18px georgia;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom:2px solid #222222;
}


#footer{
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px 0;
}

#footer a{
    color: #FFFF80;
}

.innertube{
    margin: 10px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each column (to provide padding)*/
    margin-top: 0;
}  

body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background:#f7f7f7;
}

b{font-size: 110%;}
em{color: red;}

#maincontainer{
    width: 1000px; /*Width of main container*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*Center container on page*/

}

#topsection{
    background: #f0f0f0;
    height: 90px; /*Height of top section*/
}

#topsection h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#content-container{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
    margin-top:-22px;

    margin-left:-1px;
    height:auto;

}

#contentwrapper{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;

}

#contentcolumn{
    margin-right: 310px; /*Set right margin to RightColumnWidth*/
    background:none;
    padding:15px;
    clear:both;

}

#rightcolumn{
    float: left;
    width: 310px; /*Width of right column*/
    margin-left: -311px; /*Set left margin to -(RightColumnWidth) */
    background: none;
    padding-top:20px;
    margin-top:1px;
    border-left:1px solid #222222;
}

#rightcolumn h2{
    font:18px georgia;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom:2px solid #222222;
}


#footer{
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px 0;
}

#footer a{
    color: #FFFF80;
}

.innertube{
    margin: 10px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each column (to provide padding)*/
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

HTML code

```
<div id="maincontainer">    
   <div id="topsection"><div class="innertube"><h1>CSS Fixed Layout #2.2- (Fixed-Fixed)</h1></div>
</div>

<div id="content-container">
   <div id="contentwrapper">
    <div id="contentcolumn">
      <div class="innertube">
         content here
      </div> 
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="rightcolumn">
    <div class="innertube">
      content here
    </div>
</div>
</div>

   <div id="footer"><a href="#">UIasdfg</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It should be this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504

Comment: This is your JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DXgkP/

Comment: it is not working. try putting some content in the rightcolumn div or contentcolumn div  .  the content-container height do not increase with the increase in height of these two divs

Comment: It does not effect anything, but why do you have 3 containers for innertube?

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DXgkP/3/)

Your code seems to work fine, only minor tips to work it smoothly :

- give `body` `height:100%;`
- In the class `innertube`, use a paragrap to show the content, this way, u'll achieve a better flexibilty in showing big text paras.
  use `word-break: break-all` for para

  like this

`<div class="innertube">
     <p style="word-break: break-all;">
           content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here 
     </p>
 </div>`

and `clear:both` to clear all floats in the end :

```
</div> <!-- #content-container -->
 <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: @Alex : whats the issue that you are getting...fiddle seemed to work fine, can you show your problem in fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured it out. Using the same JsFiddle I created... I added a small tweak to only one of your CSS elements, which is below. We went from:

```
   #contentcolumn {
       margin-right: 310px;
       /*Set right margin to RightColumnWidth*/
       background:none;
       padding:15px;
       clear:both;
   }
```

and then all i added was a simple display which ended up being:

```
   #contentcolumn {
       margin-right: 310px;
       /*Set right margin to RightColumnWidth*/
       background:none;
       padding:15px;
       clear:both;
    display:inline;
   }
```

This enables whatever is inside of that div to maintain being inside of that div. Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DXgkP/4/) that provides a better example of what I am saying.

A few things to note, I did add in a background color so that you could effectively see what was changing, as well as I added a height, which doesn't need to be there.. again, I added that to show you what was happening with the innermost div.

One really awesome tool that can help you understand why this works is the [Almanac](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/), which will show you many tools to help you with any CSS needs. I do want to point out that @Mr.Alien's [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504) question is another resource that is well beyond the Almanac's explanation. Let me know if you need anything else :)