# setting two divs side by side and third one below that

Tags: html, css, css-float

How do I setup two div's side by side and the third one below that like this

[image: output].

My current code is as below which puts note div after name div

HTML:

```
<div id="info_div">
    <div id="info_div_name">Name</div>
    <div id="info_div_time">6:30 PM</div>
    <div id="info_div_note">Note</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#contact_table_data {
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
    background-color:#99cc33;
    max-width:400px;
}

#info_div_name {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
    float:left;
}

#info_div_time {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
    float:right;
}

#info_div_note {
    width:inherit;
    height:auto;
    position:static;
    padding: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Look for child-nth in css. Is a good thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code will do. You should have to clear the floats.

```
#info_div_note {
clear: both;
width: inherit;
height: auto;
position: static;
padding: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `clear: both;`

Add CSS

```
#info_div_note {
    clear:both;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/66WzC/)

Comment: You don't need `clear:both;` if you use `inline-block` and you don't need `inline-block` if you use `float`

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear: both;` before `<div id="info_div_note">Note</div>` to clear the floating elements, and that will solve your issue.

```
<div id="info_div">
    <div id="info_div_name">Name</div>
    <div id="info_div_time">6:30 PM</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="info_div_note">Note</div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uXgam/)

Now this is not an optimal solution, as you will have to add that clearing `div` everytime, so better wrap the floated elements inside a `div` and use clear fix ... So your DOM will be like

```
<div id="info_div">
    <div class="self_clear">
        <div id="info_div_name">Name</div>
        <div id="info_div_time">6:30 PM</div>
    </div>
    <div id="info_div_note">Note</div>
</div>
```

And than use a `class` like

```
.self_clear:after {
   clear: both;
   display: table;
   content: "";
}
```

You can refer my answer's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504) for more information

---

And you won't require `static` as that's the default element `position`

Answer (score 1):

```
#contact_table_data {
width:inherit;
height:inherit;
background-color:#99cc33;
max-width:400px;
}

#info_div_name {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
    float:left;
}

#info_div_time {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
    float:right;
}

#info_div_note {
    clear: both;
    width:inherit;
    height:auto;
    position:static;
    padding: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3hzv/1/)