# span aligns different with text and without text

Tags: html, css

I have a span with a background image, but it aligns differently without text in it, how can i have them aligned independent of the content?

For this it has to be inline-block and it has to be a css only solution.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9YUdb/3/).

HTML:

```
Test
<span class="test">Blafffff</span>
<span class="test"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.test
{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -15px;
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/vYiCjoF.png") no-repeat;
}
```

EDIT: Thanks for the answers so far, but it has to align with the other text around it, i updated the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9YUdb/3/)

Comment: please give float:left property..it wil be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `display: inline-block;` so the `span` will align to the *baseline*, hence use `vertical-align: top;` to align them consistently.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/9YUdb/1/)

```
.test {
    /* Other properties */
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use `float: left;` here, than you won't need `vertical-align` property, but than you need to make sure that you `clear` the floating elements.

---

For more information on `float` and `clear`, you can refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504).

Comment: Thanks, but now it doesn't align with the other text around it, i updated the example.

Comment: @JohnSmith : remove `margin-top: -15px;` because that is causing the problem in alignment => http://jsfiddle.net/9YUdb/4/

Comment: @NoobEditor I removed that and made it more standard

Comment: @Mr.Alien : wrapping in another `div` with `line-height` will cause probs if there is more than 1 line of text!! :p

Comment: @NoobEditor Well, yes, but here it doesn't seem that he has more than one line.. if not than obviously the negative margin should be removed

Comment: @Mr.Alien : your solution goes with assumption that there isn't more than 1 line of text, my assumption goes opposite...let OP decide what he wants...we gave 2 solutions..job done!! :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/9YUdb/2/

```
.test
{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;

}
```

Comment: You don't need `inline-block` if you use `float: left;`

Answer (score 0):

To align with the text around it, you'll need to give the span some content. You can do that with a `:before` pseudo-element. Putting it a zero-width non-breaking space will do the trick. i.e.

```
.test:before {
    content: '\FEFF';
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/9YUdb/6/