# css overflow issue with two division

Tags: html, css, css-float

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNhet/) 
I have two `Div` , one is in table and other , outside of table .
My problem is , as you can see ,  `divOne` overflow outside of parent `Div` .
I want to show like

```
 ---------------------
|  ----    ----       |
| |    |  | D2 |      |
| | D1 |  |    |      |
| |    |   ----       |
| |    |              | 
|  ----               |
 ---------------------
```

Here is my code ,

**html**

```
   <div class="wrapper">
    <textarea rows="12" cols="8" class="divOne">
        Division One
    </textarea>    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
    <textarea rows="6" cols="8" class="divOne">    
     Division Two
     </textarea>    
            </td>
        </tr>        
    </table>    
      </div>
```

**Css**

```
.wrapper
{   
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    min-height: 50px;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;   
    line-height:normal;     
}

.divOne
{
   float:left;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue over there is that you are using floats but you aren't clearing

```
.wrapper:after { /* Using a clearfix */
    display: table;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fNhet/2/)

So, the parent takes the `height` of the non floated elements... and thus the `background` doesn't increase.

For more information on `float` and `clear`, read my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734).

Comment: I love Stackoverflow :)

Comment: @zey He he, read those answers and you will get the detailed information on the behavior :)

Comment: Yes , i have gave +1 for useful answer , and thank you !

Comment: @zey it's so good to see that so many ppl answered your question....... i am so happy to be a part of it.....

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/fNhet/1/

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: No offence with the answer but this is not the solution to the question :) you are changing the display property of the parent element which is a block level, so you shouldn't alter, the issue is of **uncleared floats**

Answer (score 1):

In your css try addding to your .wrapper
CSS:-

```
overflow:hidden;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shadowstrike/H5CFC/).This will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

use `display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: 50%` .. this will give you some additional effect

Answer (score 1):

> Add **display:inline-block;** to wrapper div then you can get the result.....