# How to get textarea to float properly around a floating element

Tags: css, css-float, textarea

How can I get the text in a textarea to flow around a floating div like any other div does without problem?

Here are three elements:

```
<div class=float1>bla bla</div>
<div class=div1>div flowing normally</div>
<textarea class=textarea1>textarea not flowing normally</textarea>
```

CSS:

```
.float1 {
    width:200px;
    float:right;
}

.div1, .textarea1 {
    width:400px;
    height:70px;
}

.div1 { 
    background-color:green;
    /*display:inline-block;*/
}

.textarea1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    border:0px;
    resize: none;    
}
```

Look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeJkU/1065/) in which div1 flow normally but I can't get the textarea to flow the same way...

Thanks!

Comment: First of all your floating is incorrect.. take a read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504) how they work

Comment: @Mr.Alien Could you be more precise as I really can't see how it's "incorrect"?