# Div Positioning is not as Expected

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following PHP page

```
<?php include 'header-adminpanel.php'; ?>
<div class="container">

    <div class="body-content">
        <div class="side-left"><?php include 'adminproduct_sidebar.php'; ?></div>
        <div class="side-right"></div>

    </div> 

</div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Where I expected the output as 
[image]

But the real output is
[image]

Styling is as follows;

```
.side-left{

     width: 250px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;


}
.side-right{

     width: 750px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;


}
.body-content{
        height:auto;
    width: 1000px;
    margin:auto;


} 
.container {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Without those "side-left" and "side-right" divs it looks fine as below
[image]

What's wrong with my code? Any Suggestions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this before including footer. That should solve the things.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: generally when you give float styles to div it is a genral solution whenever you come across things like this..

Answer (score 1):

Add

`<div style="clear:both"></div>`

before the line,

```
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using floated elements and they collapsed as there is no content.

Add [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best/1633170#1633170) to `body-content`.

Also take a look at [Why doesn't the height of a container element increase if it contains floated elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it?lq=1) and [What does the CSS rule clear: both do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css)

Answer (score 1):

add Clear both before footer div, Try the following

```
<?php include 'header-adminpanel.php'; ?>
<div class="container">

    <div class="body-content">
        <div class="side-left"><?php include 'adminproduct_sidebar.php'; ?></div>
        <div class="side-right"></div>

    </div> 

</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ps5vx/)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that the footer is sliding to the right side of the '.container' is because '.container' div's child have a float property.

So for a quick fix add 'clear:both' to the '.container' div and also to the footer div or empty div.

If this does not fix the problem we need to see the footer, side-left and slid-right html.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Two Solution

First Clearing Floats Using Clear:both

And Another Adding Overflow: auto to Parent div

HERE IS CODE

HTML :

```
<div class="body-content">
    <div class="side-left"><?php include 'adminproduct_sidebar.php'; ?></div>
    <div class="side-right"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Another solution is

Just adding a css

```
.body-content{
overflow:auto;
}
```

Hope it helps you :)