# Float div to left, other div to right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adjust float part of my menu to the left, and the other part to the right. However, I cannot get it to work.

I have been trying to accomplish it using `float`s, but I can't quite get it to work.

How can I do this in a proper way?

HTML

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="title">Title</div>

    <div class="topbar-boxes">

        <div class="topbar-boxes-left">
            <div class="topbar-box">Box1</div>
            <div class="topbar-box">Box2</div>
            <div class="topbar-box">Box3</div>
        </div>

        <div class="topbar-boxes-right">
            <div class="topbar-box">Box1</div>
            <div class="topbar-box">Box2</div>
            <div class="topbar-box">Box3</div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.topbar {
    width: 100%;

    padding: 14px;

    font-size: 18pt;
    color: white;

    background-color: rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.95);
}

.title {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

.topbar-boxes {
    float: left;
    margin: -14px;
}

.topbar-boxes-left {
    float: left;    
}

.topbar-boxes-right {
    float: right;
}

.topbar-box {
    float: left;

    padding: 20px;

    border-left: 1px solid black;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8eqSN/

Comment: Learn [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16568504/1542290) to know how floats work.

Comment: Try to use float for one of your classes and not use it for all of them

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you're floating the `.topbar-boxes` div. When you float, the length of the element is made as thin as possible (rather than filling the width of the page as you'd expect normally), so your float *is working*, you just can't see it because the parent div is only as wide as the child elements.

To fix, remove this float:

```
.topbar-boxes {
    /*float: left; <----- remove this.*/
    margin: -14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `float` elements depends on the `width` of the parent to be positioned since the parent of the boxes `topbar-boxes` is floated too it `width` isn't 100%.

Based on your structure and since the *tittle* is floated too I suggest you remove that container and all works fine taking the margin on the others:

```
.topbar-boxes-left {
  margin: -14px;
  float: left;    
}
.topbar-boxes-right {
  margin: -14px;
  float: right;
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8eqSN/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

The container div (.topbar-boxes) has a width:auto, by default in every element. That means that its width is going to be as much as its content.

Try to set width:100% in the .topbar-boxes.