# CSS positioning of two horizontal elements

Tags: html, css, html-table

How do I align foo to left and bar link to right?

```
<td>
  <span>foo</span>
  <span><a href="">bar</a></span>
</td>
```

Comment: Use CSS `float` attribute.. Either Inline Or in ur css file

Comment: I see you are using `td` then you can use `td > span{ display: table-cell; }` and then give `text-align: left` to the first span and `text-align: right` to the second span. Not a better solution but it is one of many approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `float` to achieve that

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/488aZ/)

```
td span:first-of-type {
   float: left;
}

td span:last-of-type {
   float: right;
}
```

Note that the pseudo I am using will target the first and the last `span` respectively, but if you are looking to support legacy versions of IE or other browsers, this will fail, using *unique* `class` for each `span` is recommended instead.

---

The only reason am using pseudo here is it saves me to declare classes, this is a huge advantage if you want to do this for each `td`

---

Also, I assume that you are not well informed for `float` or you must have tried to do so, if that's the case, you can refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504) for detailed information over `float` and also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734), *which isn't necessary for this scenario* because you are using `float` in `td` except the floated elements, but if you have any elements or text apart from these two elements in the same `td` than make sure you `clear` the floating elements.

Comment: I would take this as the best approach for the reasons given. I would strongly avoid using inline CSS.

Answer (score 1):

```
td > span:first-child {
    float: left;
}
td > span:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Px4un/**

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline styles, like this:

```
<td>
     <span style="float: left;">foo</span>
     <span style="float: right"><a href="">bar</a></span>
</td>
```

Or plain CSS:

```
<style>
.left {
     float: left;
}

.right {
     float: right;
} 
</style>

<td>
     <span class="left">foo</span>
     <span class="right"><a href="">bar</a></span>
</td>
```

Please, don't use pseudo elements, like :first-child or :first-of-type, because it will be not cross-browser.

Comment: For example, :last-child will not work in IE below 9th version.