# Strange behaviour div and float:left

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have this sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="float:left;" id="1">
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid black;" id="2">
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The contents of div 2 is placed left of the contents of div 1 (fine), but the border of div 2 contains div 1. This happen in all tested browsers (Firefox 26.0 and IE8).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9LdTa/1/)

Can you please explain what is going on?

Comment: remove float:left from first div..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9LdTa/2/

Comment: @Quantas may I know why did you removed float tag from the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you aren't floating another `div` - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9LdTa/)

And since it's not floated, it will take entire horizontal space, also it won't shift down as you aren't clearing your floats.

So what happens is the floated `div` just sits to the left, making your non floated `div` wrap around it..

If you move the order of your `div` in the markup, you will understand what I meant - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9LdTa/3/) So, as you see, the top `div` takes all the horizontal space available, whereas the other `div` sits on the left, won't take entire horizontal space as it's floated to the left, so since you have the floated `div` first and next is non floated `div` it will take up `100%` space, but will wrap around the floating `div` since you haven't cleared it, so you should `float` the next `div` as well.

The same effect can be achieved using `display: inline-block;` as well.

For more information on how floats work, refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504)

```
<div style="float:left;" id="1">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid black; float: left;" id="2">
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
</div>
```

Comment: this indeed is the right answer, how comes the floating div is inglobed in the other one thought?

Comment: @Onheiron I explained :) you can read my other answer which covers floats in detail, when you float them, they get out of the flow, so the next element will move up... unless the floated element is cleared, so you feel the `div` is inglobed :)

Comment: @lesto it is out of the document flow but not like `position: absolute;` so it will keep it's space reserved, nudging the text of the div to wrap around, if you expect overlay, than here you go http://jsfiddle.net/9LdTa/4/ :)

Comment: Thank you, as last request how do you know about this thing? there are paper about this or you readed the RFC?

Comment: @lesto Studying, experience, you can refer articles online and try and keep testing :) you can read one good article [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/)