# Border does not extend past floated elements?

Tags: html, css, django

I have the following code to present a set of images. The images are filtered by date and they include a caption underneath. Pictures are placed as a grid on next to other. The code

html

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
    <title>Images</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="date-group">
        <div class='date-title'>
             13/02/2014
        </div>
        <div class="date-content">
            <div class="img-thumb float">
                <a href="../images/bold.jpg">
                    <img src="../images/bold.jpg">
                    <span class="caption">A big caption that might be going in more than one lines</span>                

                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="img-thumb float">
                <a href="../images/bold.jpg"><img src="../images/bold.jpg"></a>
                <span class="caption">A caption</span>                
            </div>
            <div class="img-thumb float">
                <a href="../images/bold.jpg"><img src="../images/bold.jpg"></a>
                <span class="caption">A caption</span>                
            </div>
            <div class="img-thumb float">
                <a><img src="../images/bold.jpg"></a>
                <span class="caption">A caption</span>                
            </div>
            <div class="img-thumb float">
                <a><img src="../images/bold.jpg"></a>
                <span class="caption">A caption</span>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
div.date-group {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.date-group img{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

.img-thumb{
    width:100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.date-group span{
    display: block;
}

.float{
    float: left;
}

.date-title{
    height:20px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.date-content{
    margin-right: 10px;
    min-height: 150px;

}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkPR7/). My problems is that the border does not grow as the caption might grow when it wraps to more than one line. Also will this code won't make images go to second and third row if the first one is full. How can I change those two things (the border growing and .img-thumb float to change row when not enough space. Also keep in mind that these images will populate the page automatically(if it is possible) within a for in a django template

Comment: It is because of this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504 .... and here's a fixed version -> http://jsfiddle.net/jkPR7/3/

Comment: You could just put `overflow: hidden;` on `div.date-group `. This will fix the border. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/jkPR7/5/)

Comment: @Ruddy Bad approach for clearing floats :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Na its not, that's fine! Quick and easy, I have never ran into a problem using this method.

Comment: @Ruddy I don't think so :) http://jsfiddle.net/pHZs2/

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem with all methods answered (overflow, table-cell etc) is that when the image changes row it wont go underneath the first, becuase its caption is wrapped in more than one line. It goes next to it. How to deal with that? I should probably give a max-width correct?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Like I said I have never run into a problem with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Apostolos try this one:

```
.float{ display: inline-block; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkPR7/24/)

Comment: It seems that you are a life saver. Why did i need it that. Could you please explain?

Comment: div elements by default are block elements, meaning that they are going to block entire horizontal space, so when you make them display: inline-block than they are not going to take the whole space. So this way img-thumb elements are going to be next to each other.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when I use it in my actual code.

Comment: and if you wanna remove space between img-thumb use this one: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jkPR7/25/)

Comment: Works in fiddle but not in my code on chrome. Did u change sth else in code?Sometimes I just hate CSS :).EDIT Works in my actual Code, probably something i did :)!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

you should use this css

```
.date-content {
    margin-right: 10px;
    min-height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YQ8QE/)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but now when image goes to next row it will gow next to the big caption and not under it.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `div.date-group {display: inline-block;}` 
http://jsfiddle.net/jkPR7/11/

Comment: Here also, Image places itself next to the image with the big caption and underneath when changing row and not exactly under it.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/jkPR7/12/

That's all

```
.date-group span{
    display: table-cell;
}

.date-content{
    margin-right: 10px;
    min-height: 150px;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: The same, when image goes to next row, it will place itself next to the big caption and not under it

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your CSS:

```
.date-content:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

Edited fidle: http://jsfiddle.net/jkPR7/27/

Learn more http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/