# CSS div margin/padding error

Tags: html, css, margin

As you can see by this fiddle here in white middle column (it is supposed to be coloured but jsfiddle wont for some reason) there is padding either side that leaves a horrible white strip down each side. I can't seem to find what is causing it though. Can anyone here have a crack at it? It does make it hard to see because obviously the color is the same but here is what it looks like normally. I need the 3 columns do be touching is all. Thanks for your help, I'm sure it's nothing too difficult.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/d9aSS/

```
    body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;           
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
    min-width:600px;        
    font-size:90%;
}
```

Stack overflow wanted some code with the link, please ignore.

Comment: Total disaster of CSS float...

Comment: Any idea how I would fix this?

Comment: By learning how floats work?

Comment: Thank You, I used float:clear

Comment: @user3286723 That is not even a valid alue.

Comment: You should start again from scratch, this code is a little bit messy ;). do not use stuff like `right : 50%`. Using float and width should be enough.

Comment: aaah man so many float...

Comment: I guess you are not aware of how floats work, have a read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504)

Answer (score 0):

```
.colright, .colmid, .colleft {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
```

}

Remove the float: left; line to correct this... Hope it will help you... If any doubt ask...