# Elements doesn't float beside each other, instead renders below another element

Tags: html, css, css-float

Why aren't these two elements next to each other?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gX3sB/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div> 
    <p>I'm a paragraph and I'm on the left!!!</p> 
    <h3>I'm a header and I'm on the right</h3> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div p{
    float: left;
    width:30%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

div h3{
    clear: both;
    float:left;
    width:10%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I thought by giving the `h3` a `clear: both` would use the empty space next to the `p`.

But it didn't work. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: are you looking for this:- http://jsfiddle.net/gX3sB/3/

Comment: or for this: http://jsfiddle.net/gX3sB/4/

Comment: because of `clear: both`.. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gX3sB/5/).

Comment: ow I thought that clear:both was to use the white space :s Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `clear: both;` will clear the floats and will render the element below, inorder to make that work, you need to take out `clear: both;` from `div h3` selector.

Also, if you want to `float` the header to the `right` you need to use `float: right;` rather using `left`.

This is what the `clear: both;` does to your example, it kinda acts like a wall between two floated elements.

[image]

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504) of mine will help you to understand how floats really work and [the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css/12871734#12871734) will help you understand clear both.

---

`clear: both;` is to clear the floated elements, so in your code, you should create a snippet of something like

```
.clear:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

And now use the above snippet on your container element which will self clear the element like, rest stays the same but as I said you need to remove `clear: both;` from `div h3`

```
<div class="clear"> 
    <p>I'm a paragraph and I'm on the left!!!</p> 
    <h3>I'm a header and I'm on the right</h3> 
</div>
```

---

**What will happen if I don't clear the floats?**

Well, say you have a `background` applied to the parent element, the color won't render at all, see it yourself...

<kbd><s>[**Demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/hv75X/)</s></kbd> *(floats aren't cleared so you don't see the `red` background)*

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/hv75X/1/)</kbd> *(floats are cleared, you can see a `red` background now)*

---

It's not just about the `background-color`, if you have third element, than it will just sit beside the other two, so inorder to prevent that, we use `clear: both;` as well. I've covered these aspects in the answers I provided the link for.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't next to each other because you disabled any floating left of `h3` with `clear:both`. Remove that and they will. Like so http://jsfiddle.net/vHph8/

Answer (score 1):

The css `clear` property resets the floating and actually causes the layout to proceed beneath all floating material.

if you delete it from your css, it works (jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gX3sB/2/)).