# CSS - li a href parent is smaller than child

Tags: html, css

i style simple list of articles, i just found out that my a href on image is smaller than actual image and its not right as soon as its his parent. And i don't know how to fix it,
This is how it looks:
[image]

My HTML looks like:

```
<div id="article-container">

<ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/foto.jpg" alt="Popis"></a>
            <h2><a href="#">Název článku</a></h2>
            <p><span><strong>28. 2. 2014 8:29</strong> od Dwandy</span><br>
              Ahoj, jak se máš? Já úplně úžasně a úpe nejvíc. Závidíš, he? </p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#" class="links">Přečíst</a><br>
              <a href="#">4 reakce</a></p>
            <hr>
       </li>

  <li><a href="#"><img src="images/foto.jpg" alt="Popis"></a>
           <h2><a href="#">Název článku</a></h2>
           <p><span><strong>28. 2. 2014 8:29</strong> od Dwandy</span><br>
             Ahoj, jak se máš? Já úplně úžasně a úpe nejvíc. Závidíš, he? </p>
           <p class="more"><a href="#" class="links">Přečíst</a><br>
             <a href="#">4 reakce</a></p>
           <hr>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/foto.jpg" alt="Popis"></a>
           <h2><a href="#">Název článku</a></h2>
           <p><span><strong>28. 2. 2014 8:29</strong> od Dwandy</span><br>
             Ahoj, jak se máš? Já úplně úžasně a úpe nejvíc. Závidíš, he? </p>
           <p class="more"><a href="#" class="links">Přečíst</a><br>
             <a href="#">4 reakce</a></p>
           <hr>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

My CSS looks like:

```
#article-container{
  width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:#4d4d4d;
    font-size:90%;
  height: 144px;
}

#article-container br, hr {
    display:none;
}
#article-container ul {
    width:960px;
  height: 144px
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:15px 0;
}
#article-container li {
    width:310px;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 8px;
}
#article-container a{
    display:block;
}
#article-container img {
    float:left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0
}
#article-container a img {
    border:2px solid #999e8a;
}
#article-container a:hover img {
    border-color:#000
}
#article-container h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-size:110%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#article-container h2 a {
    color:#4d4d4d
}
#article-container h2 a:hover {
    color:#840000
}
#article-container p {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    margin:0
}
#article-container p span {
    display:block;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0
}
#article-container p.more {
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
    overflow:hidden
}


#article-container p.more a {
    color:#2e79bc;
    line-height: 27px;
}
#article-container p.more a:hover {
    color:#840000
}
#article-container p.more a.links {
    float:right;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background:#2e79bc;
    color:#fff;
    margin-right:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:3px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
#article-container p.more a.links:hover {
    background:#000
}
```

Demo : [FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qB8V4/)  Whole [WEBSITE DEMO](http://funedit.com/andurit/new/)

Can somebody help me to make this  same width height as image?

Comment: [Read why it happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `<img/>` is floatting , `<a>` doesn't wrap it. Trigger layout with `overflow` or `float` .

---

`<edit>` About dealing with floatting elements : see: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/`</edit>`

---

http://fiddle.jshell.net/qB8V4/1/
`float` seems to be what you need here .

---

then , you still neeed to manage floatting interaction behavior setting `overflow` to elements aside it, such as : `<p>`, `<h2>` :

http://fiddle.jshell.net/qB8V4/2/

Comment: hey man, it help but it also destroy the "date" text style :)

Comment: what do you mean , destroy ?

Comment: You can see it on your own demo :) the date "28. 2. 2014 8:29" is in other line then it should be  and everything is a bit moved

Comment: right, i just saw it and updated the fiddle . http://fiddle.jshell.net/qB8V4/2/ . (layout to trigger )

Comment: i added overflow to h2 an p , to trigger layout, so elements wraps floatting element inside and sees the floatting element standing aside/outside.

Comment: oh mate it actualy not looks fine in firefox, check this : http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_11750681601398598462.jpg

And doing the same to my friend on chrome :(

Comment: still FLOATTING issues and probably some padding/margin not collapsing anymore since you partially fix layout issues

Comment: is there a chance you can help me to fix it?

Comment: i guess, but in my ff or chtome , i see no bug online at this time ? did you update your live site ?

Comment: i think it can be because of that <p> style if u check on it in borowser its is/ to another element as well

Comment: i did, you can see easy that bug with zoom size (ctrl + scroll up)

Comment: okay i see it , when you zoom this way you increase font-size and the white-space in between li. Reduce a little font-size for ul , down to 80% for instance (inspector tells me it is set at 90%)

Comment: Its uploaded, but isnt there other way how to fix it? Beausee this is just about how  much user zoom the site or with what resolution he come on site

Comment: set `#article-container{font-size:80%;}` and 
`#article-container li {font-size:120%;}` to fix your zooming behavior, so white-space in between inline-boxes won't groww to much

Comment: Also when text is smaller its harder to read it and its not copy of .psd i had :)

Comment: do the update i advise , and let's see what happens :)

Comment: done, but i add 70% and 130% , right if i zoom out a lot it fails but not in normal us i believe, or is there way how to make it 100% fix?

Comment: make your li floatting instead inline-block, so no need to deal with font-size anymore :) `#article-container li {float:left;}`

Answer (score 0):

It is a float problem. just put **overflow:hidden** to your css  element **#article-container a.**

Test:
http://jsbin.com/yavegeru/1/

Comment: overflow will send h2 and p below the <a> with image. not sure this is what OP is looking for.

Comment: No it won't. Let's make a sample.

Comment: unless <a> is not at display:block; anymore :)

Comment: Your example wraps everything into <a> , but OP html has  others links, like in <h2>. and you cannot wrap a link into another one. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The important thing in here is using overflow:hidden to fix floating problem.

Comment: overflow is not the only way, it's a matter of layout , display, float , position have some ways too to trigger it :) . You need to pick up the one that will suits the best. each situation are different