# Make a parent div expand to fit a div contained within it

Tags: html, css

Apologies if this has been covered elsewhere. I am not a pro and I have two templates that are work in progress for the new design of my web site.

They can be seen at:

http://www.purpleski.com/template.aspx

http://www.purpleski.com/template2.aspx

Template at

template1.aspx

shows how it works fine with just simple content.

I think the problem I have is obvious but I can not get the `div id="main"` to expand as the content of the tabs expand.

The relevant css files are at

`www.purpleski.com/css/fws2.css`
`www.purpleski.com/css/menu.css`
`www.purpleski.com/css/indexpage_only.css`

Hope somebody can help.

Thank you.

michael

Comment: [probably floats issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it/16568504#16568504)

Comment: slightly off topic, but the title at template.aspx says 'purle ski' instead of purple :P

Comment: work in progress. These things are not important at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

`#tab-content1` is positioned absolutely, so it takes 0px height (element is moved from document).

Remove `position: absolute` (and `float left` from parent LI -- or set `width` to parent `LI`).

Comment: Hi thanks for this. Followed your instructions but this pushes the tab 100% of the width of the main div and the other tabs below the first tab. See http://www.purpleski.com/templateMain.aspx

Comment: What you exactly need? `.tabs {overflow: hidden;} .tabs li {float: left; width: 33.3%}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change css of div id="main" to like this in template2.

```
#main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 920px;
    bottom: 158;
}
```

and for template 1 remove position:absolute from tab-content1 class.

Answer (score 0):

Hi managed to get it to work with different code

http://css-tricks.com/organic-tabs/

It is good. Just have to watch the different files jquery files beng called and in what order they are on the page.

Thanks for everybody's help.