# Float seems to removing the background color

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to create navigation menu and I've added `float: right;` to my `li` tag in css, I also have div named `.header` which happens to be the background of the menu.

From some reason, when I add float the background just dissapears and when I removed the float the background has returned to his place.

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    height:  10%;
    background: #616161;
}
ul#nav{
    list-style: none;
}
ul#nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 25px;
    float: right;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="header">
 <ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="#">Website</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

My code is pure, no css, no margin, only display that might be causing this problem of background positioning.

Is there a possibility to keep the text in right float and background together?

Before and after float using:

[image]

[image]

Comment: A jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem will help.

Comment: try add `overflow: hidden;` to `.header`

Comment: could you provide HTML structure of your `.header`?

Comment: Also have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-does-css-float-work-why-doesnt-the-height-of-a-container-element-increase?lq=1 ♦ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css

Comment: @HashemQolami It's not a duplicated, since the sulotion you gave me doesn't work.

Comment: Better check carefully that responses. This question is an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before `</ul>` put this line [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4htfwjy6/1/)

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

it should work or add

```
.header {overflow:hidden;}
```

as suggested by @MaryMelody - [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/4htfwjy6/)

Comment: I've tried this code and placed it below .header div and it does not change a thing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4htfwjy6/1/ it is working here or you can add overflow: hidden; to .header as @Mary Melody told