# Input section inside a container can't be selected

Tags: html, css

I created a form using phpform. org/. Under the section "Detailed Room Information", "Parking & Vehicle Storage", and "HOA/Management Company Continued..." I tried organizing them into columns using these example:

- http://pagecolumn.com/htmlcodes4.htm
- http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hack

But once I did, the elements can't be selected for inputs.

How do I organize those elements using a container properly?

TIP: In the CSS when I delete the Float property it works fine, but is not positioned where I want it.

http://jsfiddle.net/e23fa7z0/

CSS:

```
body
{
    background:#fffff;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    margin:8px 0 16px;
    text-align:center;
}

#form_container
{
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    width:960px;
}

#top
{
    display:block;
    height:10px;
    margin:10px auto 0;
    width:960px;
}

#footer
{
    width:960px;
    clear:both;
    color:#999999;
    text-align:center;
    width:960px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 85%;
}

#footer a{
    color:#999999;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #999999;
}

#bottom
{
    display:block;
    height:10px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:960px;
}

#container1 {

}

form.appnitro
{
    margin:20px 20px 0;
    padding:0 0 20px;
}

/**** Logo Section  *****/
h1
{
    background-color:#dedede;
    margin:0;
    min-height:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-indent:-8000px;

}

h1 a
{

    display:block;
    height:100%;
    min-height:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

h4
{
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:175%;
    font-weight:700;
    margin:0 0 5px;
}


img
{
    behavior:url(css/iepngfix.htc);
    border:none;
}

/**** 3 Columns ****/
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#col1 {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
}
#col2 {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
}
#col3 {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
}

/**** 4 Columns ****/
.wrapper{
   margin: 20px auto;

   width: 960px;


}

.left1{
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
   width: 150px;

}
.left2{
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
   width: 150px;

}
.left3{
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
   width: 150px;

}
.right{
   float: right;
   width: 450px;

}

/**** 5 Columns ****/
#container5 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#sec1 {
    float:left;
    width:19.5%;
    padding-right: 1px;
}
#sec2 {
    float:left;
    width:19.5%;
    padding-right: 1px;
}
#sec3 {
    float:left;
    width:19.5%;
    padding-right: 1px;
}
#sec4 {
    float:left;
    width:19.5%;
    padding-right: 1px;
}
#sec5 {
    float:left;
    width:19.5%;
    padding-right: 1px;
}

/**** Form Section ****/
.appnitro
{
    font-family:Lucida Grande, Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
}

.appnitro li
{
    width:61%;
}

form ul
{
    font-size:100%;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

form li
{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:4px 5px 2px 9px;
    position:relative;
}

form li:after
{
    clear:both;
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.buttons:after
{
    clear:both;
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.buttons
{
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    margin-top:10px;
}

* html form li
{
    height:1%;
}

* html .buttons
{
    height:1%;
}

* html form li div
{
    display:inline-block;
}

form li div
{
    color:#444;
    margin:0 4px 0 0;
    padding:0 0 8px;
}

form li span
{
    color:#444;
    float:left;
    margin:0 4px 0 0;
    padding:0 0 8px;
}

form li div.left
{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:48%;
}

form li div.right
{
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    width:48%;
}

form li div.left .medium
{
    width:100%;
}

form li div.right .medium
{
    width:100%;
}

.clear
{
    clear:both;
}

form li div label
{
    clear:both;
    color:#444;
    display:block;
    font-size:9px;
    line-height:9px;
    margin:0;
    padding-top:3px;
}

form li span label
{
    clear:both;
    color:#444;
    display:block;
    font-size:9px;
    line-height:9px;
    margin:0;
    padding-top:3px;
}

form li .datepicker
{
    cursor:pointer !important;
    float:left;
    height:16px;
    margin:.1em 5px 0 0;
    padding:0;
    width:16px;
}

.form_description
{
    border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;
    clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 0 9px;
}

.form_description[class]
{
    display:block;
}

.form_description h2
{
    clear:left;
    font-size:225%;
    font-weight:700;
    margin:0 0 3px;
}

.form_description p
{
    font-size:95%;
    line-height:130%;
    margin:0 0 12px;
}

form hr
{
    display:none;
}

form li.section_break
{
    border-top:1px dotted #ccc;
    margin-top:9px;
    padding-bottom:0;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-top:13px;
    width:99.5% !important;
}

form ul li.first
{
    border-top:none !important;
    margin-top:0 !important;
    padding-top:0 !important;
}

form .section_break h3
{
    font-size:125%;
    font-weight:700;
    line-height:100%;
    margin:0 0 0px;
}

form .section_break p
{
    font-size:85%;

    margin:0 0 10px;
}

/**** Buttons ****/
input.button_text
{
    overflow:visible;
    padding:0 7px;
    width:auto;
}

.buttons input
{
    font-size:120%;
    margin-right:5px;
}

/**** Inputs and Labels ****/
label.description
{
    border:none;
    color:#222;
    display:block;
    font-size:95%;
    font-weight:700;
    line-height:150%;
    padding:0 0 1px;
}

span.symbol
{
    font-size:115%;
    line-height:130%;
}

input.text
{
    background:#fff url(../../../images/shadow.gif) repeat-x top;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    border-left:1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-right:1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-top:1px solid #7c7c7c;
    color:#333;
    font-size:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:2px 0;
}

input.file
{
    color:#333;
    font-size:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:2px 0;
}

textarea.textarea
{
    background:#fff url(../../../images/shadow.gif) repeat-x top;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    border-left:1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-right:1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-top:1px solid #7c7c7c;
    color:#333;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:100%;
    margin:0;
    width:99%;
}

select.select
{
    color:#333;
    font-size:100%;
    margin:2px 0;
    padding:2px 0;
    height: 20px;
    background:#fff url(../../../images/shadow.gif) repeat-x top;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    border-left:1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-right:1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-top:1px solid #7c7c7c;
}


input.currency
{
    text-align:right;
}

input.checkbox
{
    display:block;
    height:13px;
    line-height:1.4em;
    margin:6px 0 0 3px;
    width:13px;
}

input.radio
{
    display:block;
    height:13px;
    line-height:1.4em;
    margin:6px 0 0 3px;
    width:13px;
}

label.choice
{
    color:#444;
    display:block;
    font-size:100%;
    line-height:1.4em;
    margin:-1.55em 0 0 25px;
    padding:4px 0 5px;
    width:90%;
}

select.select[class]
{
    margin:0;
    padding:1px 0;
}

*:first-child+html select.select[class]
{
    margin:1px 0;
}

.safari select.select
{
    font-size:120% !important;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}

input.small
{
    width:100%;
}

select.small
{
    width:100%;
}

input.medium
{
    width:101%;
}

input.medium2
{
    width:90%;
}

input.medium3
{
    width:82%;
}
input.medium4
{
    width:81%;
}
input.medium5
{
    width:77%;
}
input.medium6
{
    width:73%;
}
input.medium7
{
    width:87%;
}
input.medium8
{
    width:70%;
}



select.medium
{
    width:50%;
}

input.large
{
    width:99%;
}

select.large
{
    width:100%;
}

textarea.small
{
    height:5.5em;
}

textarea.medium
{
    height:10em;
    width: 101%;
}

textarea.large
{
    height:20em;
}

/**** Errors ****/
#error_message
{
    background:#fff;
    border:1px dotted red;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    padding-top:4px;
    text-align:center;
    width:99%;
}

#error_message_title
{
    color:#DF0000;
    font-size:125%;
    margin:7px 0 5px;
    padding:0;
}

#error_message_desc
{
    color:#000;
    font-size:100%;
    margin:0 0 .8em;
}

#error_message_desc strong
{
    background-color:#FFDFDF;
    color:red;
    padding:2px 3px;
}

form li.error
{
    background-color:#FFDFDF !important;
    border-bottom:1px solid #EACBCC;
    border-right:1px solid #EACBCC;
    margin:3px 0;
}

form li.error label
{
    color:#DF0000 !important;
}

form p.error
{
    clear:both;
    color:red;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:700;
    margin:0 0 5px;
}

form .required
{
    color:red;
    float:none;
    font-weight:700;
}

/**** Guidelines and Error Highlight ****/
form li.highlighted
{
    /* background-color:#fff7c0; */
}

form .guidelines
{
    background:#f5f5f5;
    border:1px solid #e6e6e6;
    color:#444;
    font-size:80%;
    left:100%;
    line-height:130%;
    margin:0 0 0 8px;
    padding:8px 10px 9px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:42%;
    z-index:1000;
}

form .guidelines small
{
    font-size:105%;
}

form li.highlighted .guidelines
{
    visibility:visible;
}

form li:hover .guidelines
{
    visibility:visible;
}

.no_guidelines .guidelines
{
    display:none !important;
}

.no_guidelines form li
{
    width:97%;
}

.no_guidelines li.section
{
    padding-left:9px;
}

/*** Success Message ****/
.form_success 
{
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 90px 0pt 100px;
    text-align: center
}

.form_success h2 {
    clear:left;
    font-size:160%;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0pt 0pt 3px;
}

/*** Password ****/
ul.password{
    margin-top:60px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
.password h2{
    color:#DF0000;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0pt auto 10px;
}

.password input.text {
   font-size:170% !important;
   width:380px;
   text-align: center;
}
.password label{
   display:block;
   font-size:120% !important;
   padding-top:10px;
   font-weight:bold;
}

#li_captcha{
   padding-left: 5px;
}


#li_captcha span{
    float:none;
}

/** Embedded Form **/

.embed #form_container{
    border: none;
}

.embed #top, .embed #bottom, .embed h1{
    display: none;
}

.embed #form_container{
    width: 100%;
}

.embed #footer{
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 99%;
}

.embed #footer.success{
    text-align: center;
}

.embed form.appnitro
{
    margin:0px 0px 0;

}



/*** Calendar **********************/
div.calendar { position: relative; }

.calendar table {
cursor:pointer;
border:1px solid #ccc;
font-size: 11px;
color: #000;
background: #fff;
font-family:"Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.calendar .button { 
text-align: center;    
padding: 2px;          
}

.calendar .nav {
background:#f5f5f5;
}

.calendar thead .title { 
font-weight: bold;      
text-align: center;
background: #dedede;
color: #000;
padding: 2px 0 3px 0;
}

.calendar thead .headrow { 
background: #f5f5f5;
color: #444;
font-weight:bold;
}

.calendar thead .daynames { 
background: #fff;
color:#333;
font-weight:bold;
}

.calendar thead .name { 
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
padding: 2px;
text-align: center;
color: #000;
}

.calendar thead .weekend { 
color: #666;
}

.calendar thead .hilite { 
background-color: #444;
color: #fff;
padding: 1px;
}

.calendar thead .active { 
background-color: #d12f19;
color:#fff;
padding: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}


.calendar tbody .day { 
width:1.8em;
color: #222;
text-align: right;
padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
.calendar tbody .day.othermonth {
font-size: 80%;
color: #bbb;
}
.calendar tbody .day.othermonth.oweekend {
color: #fbb;
}

.calendar table .wn {
padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
background: #666;
}

.calendar tbody .rowhilite td {
background: #FFF1AF;
}

.calendar tbody .rowhilite td.wn {
background: #FFF1AF;
}

.calendar tbody td.hilite { 
padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
background:#444 !important;
color:#fff !important;
}

.calendar tbody td.active { 
color:#fff;
background: #529214 !important;
padding: 2px 2px 0px 2px;
}

.calendar tbody td.selected { 
font-weight: bold;
border: 1px solid #888;
padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
background: #f5f5f5 !important;
color: #222 !important;
}

.calendar tbody td.weekend { 
color: #666;
}

.calendar tbody td.today { 
font-weight: bold;
color: #529214;
background:#D9EFC2;
}

.calendar tbody .disabled { color: #999; }

.calendar tbody .emptycell { 
visibility: hidden;
}

.calendar tbody .emptyrow { 
display: none;
}

.calendar tfoot .footrow { 
text-align: center;
background: #556;
color: #fff;
}

.calendar tfoot .ttip { 
background: #222;
color: #fff;
font-size:10px;
border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
padding: 3px;
}

.calendar tfoot .hilite { 
background: #aaf;
border: 1px solid #04f;
color: #000;
padding: 1px;
}

.calendar tfoot .active { 
background: #77c;
padding: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}

.calendar .combo {
position: absolute;
display: none;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 4em;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background: #f5f5f5;
color: #222;
font-size: 90%;
z-index: 100;
}

.calendar .combo .label,
.calendar .combo .label-IEfix {
text-align: center;
padding: 1px;
}

.calendar .combo .label-IEfix {
width: 4em;
}

.calendar .combo .hilite {
background: #444;
color:#fff;
}

.calendar .combo .active {
border-top: 1px solid #999;
border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
background: #dedede;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: NVM, I solved it. I changed all the floats to display: inline-block;

Comment: Please don't add 'SOLVED' to question titles.

Comment: @RobbieFikes Please do not disregard the error "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code" when posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float: left` and add `overflow: hidden` to the `#container1`, `#container5` and `.wrapper` CSS entries.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/1h89ot5g/)**

*Your issue was the parent container having height 0 because the child elements were floated
-- here is a really thorough explanation of how floating works and the explanation of the issue: [How CSS Float Works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16568504/643482)

Comment: Thank you! Although I'm having a hard time visualizing why this works. Are you saying beacuse the parent div i.e. .wrapper didn't have a defined height that nothing was inside the div to float in the first place?

Comment: @RobbieFikes, I added a really helpful link to the answer that goes in-depth into how floating works and why the floated elements dont contribute to the height of the parent. You will also see that they mention the fix that we implemented for your page – setting `overflow`