# height: auto doesn't work for parent div - no overflow: auto

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My div `projects` needs to have an automatic height because the `project` classes will be later added dynamically.
The problem is that the `height: auto` attribute doesn't work.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="projects">
        <div id="Proj1" class="project col-md-4"></div>
        <div id="Proj2" class="project col-md-4"></div>
        <div id="Proj3" class="project col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="lanes">
        <div id="lane1" class="lane">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#projects {
    background-color: pink;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.project {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.lane {
    height: 155px;
    background-color: green;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

I can not use `overflow: auto` or `overflow: normal` because i have draggable divs within the `projects` div, which can't be dragged out.

Comment: **Auto** is the default value so you don't need to set that ... also this is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/atnwjq29/

Comment: Already answered.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-does-css-float-work-why-doesnt-the-height-of-a-container-element-increase

Comment: Thans for your answers. The clear:both div did the job, i have only always put it into the wrong place