# CSS vh and vw: Why does my div overlap with the div above it?

Tags: html, css, clearfix

In the following SSCCE, why does the `#sliderArea` div overlap the `#topBar` div above it, while `div` is a block-level element?

I expected it to appear below the `#topBar`?

**[JsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/qbx5vwy5/2/)**

```css
#left-div {
  float: left;
}
#right-div {
  float: right;
}
a {
  margin: 10px;
}
#topBar {
  width: 100%;
}
#sliderArea {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#four-cols {
  margin: 5px 100px 5px 100px;
}
#col-one {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 125px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#col-two {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 125px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#col-three {
  background-color: green;
  height: 125px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#col-four {
  background-color: red;
  height: 125px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="topBar">
  <div id="left-div">
    <a href="#">Login</a>
  </div>
  <div id="right-div">
    <a href="#">Menu One</a>
    <a href="#">Menu Two</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="sliderArea"></div>
<div id="four-cols">
  <div id="col-one"></div>
  <div id="col-two"></div>
  <div id="col-three"></div>
  <div id="col-four"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: a very good  explanation:
 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-does-css-float-work-why-doesnt-the-height-of-a-container-element-increase)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear the `float`s :

```
div{ clear:both; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbx5vwy5/3/)

Or just for `#sliderArea` element :

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbx5vwy5/7/)

Answer (score 2):

Add to your CSS:

```
#topBar {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

By adding ***overflow: hidden*** to the wrapper of floating elements, the browser can calculate the height of it.

Answer (score 2):

because of `float` of the childrens you will need to add

```
#topBar {
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden; <-- add this
}
```

or

```
#topBar {
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block; <-- add this
}
```

which will `clear` the `floats`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/qbx5vwy5/6/

Answer (score 1):

You can add clear where you want them to clear. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbx5vwy5/4/)

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

When you do not clear floats, they will just stick together. By adding **clear**, you will stop the floating and start a "new" float if it is necessary :)