# Element's height in css

Tags: css

I am having problem understanding the height of element in div. I have a header div which has certain divs inside it.The div inside occupy certain height. Isn't the header supposed to cover the area occupied by the elements defined inside it when the height is not mentioned. As per my understanding the header is supposed to wrap all the div inside it.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

This is my body

```
   <div style=" float:left; background-color:pink; width:20%; height:40px; ">
      THis is left
   </div>

   <div style=" float:left; background-color:gray; width:70%; height:40px; " >

        <div id="htop">
             This is top      
         </div>

       <div id="hbutt" >
          this is buttom
       </div>

  </div>
```

And here goes style

```
  #cont{ background-color:yellow; width:900px; height:300px; margin:auto; padding:40px;  }

  #header{ background-color:red; width:100%; padding:5px;  }

  #cont2{ background-color:blue; width:10%; height:auto; padding:5px; clear:both;  }

  #htop{ background-color:maroon; }

  #hbutt{  background-color:purple; }
```

For output and possible change need https://jsfiddle.net/sum1/vmq3y2rv/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-does-css-float-work-why-doesnt-the-height-of-a-container-element-increase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have floating DIVs inside any other DIV, then height does not calculated automatically for outer DIV, to make it you should add **display:inline-block** or **display:table**  to outer DIV depending on your layout.

```
 #header {
      background-color:red;
      width:100%;
      padding:5px;
    display:inline-block;
  }
```

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/vmq3y2rv/1/

Comment: to prevent affecting the properties of outer div, you can use `#outer_div:after{content: ''; display: table; clear: both;}`

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is true but when all elements are floated inside of the header it collapses.

```
.clearfix{
    clear:both;
 }
```

and then insert a div right before your header ends with a class of clearfix.

Jsfiddle is here 
https://jsfiddle.net/kriscoulson/vmq3y2rv/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can either use **float:left** or **display:inline-block/table** , It will be based on your requirements and layout.