# Adding margin-left to div after another div that has float:left

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the title, this is hard to explain in one sentence. Basically, I have a div container with two divs: 1 image that is `float:left`(ed) and another one with text. Here is what it looks like:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://boxedinfinity.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Halo3.jpg" alt="Game Image" id="gameImage">
    <div id="second">
        <h2>Genre:</h2>
        <p>First Person Shooter</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a fiddle of what I am doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/qMQL5/880/

I want to add padding to the `p` part of the div with the text. As you see, I added `margin-left:50px` to #second `p` but it doesn't do anything. Basically, I want to "indent" the text "First Person Shooter" but I am having trouble doing this. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the width of the image always known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

This is the result of your actual code now:

---

[image: p with margin not applied]

---

So, as you can see it is applying, but you have to know a few things:

- `img` tag is an [inline element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.2)

> The `IMG` element embeds an image in the current document at the
>   location of the element's definition. The `IMG` element has no content;
>   it is usually replaced inline by the image designated by the `src`
>   attribute, the exception being for left or right-aligned images that
>   are "*floated*" out of line.

- since you are floating the `img` tag it will start behaving like an `inline-block` element

> Floating an `inline` or `block` level element will make the element behave
>   like an `inline-block` element (from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16568504/3448527)).

So, therefore, there is a few solutions to fix this issue:

---

#### Solution #1

*(a quick fix [as you can see by adding a `border` to your `#container`]- I would advise to read the other solutions below)*

**only using you existing HTML markup and CSS:(which will make both `<h1>` and `<p>`** *indented*)

- make your `img` an block element by applying `display:block` (optional - to fix gap below `img` tag)
- removing `margin-left` from `p` and adding `margin-right` to `img`

```css
#container {
    border:1px solid red
}

#gameImage {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    display:block; /*new - optional*/
    margin-right:10px /*new*/
   
}
#second {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://boxedinfinity.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Halo3.jpg" alt="Game Image" id="gameImage" />
    <div id="second">
        <h2>Genre:</h2>
        <p>First Person Shooter</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Solution #2

Since you are using `float` already, let's go with [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
#container {
  background-color: green;
  border:1px solid red;
}

#second {
  float:left;
 /* background-color: green; /*choose what block  will have the background*/ }


#gameImage {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
}

#second > p {
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
```

```html
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
  <img src="http://boxedinfinity.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Halo3.jpg" alt="Game Image" id="gameImage" />
  <div id="second">
    <h2>Genre:</h2>
    <p>First Person Shooter</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Solution #3

dropping the `floats` and using `display:table/table-cell`

```css
#container {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#container > div {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#container > div:first-child, #container > div > img {
    width:100px
}
#container > div > img {
    display:block
}
#container > #second > p {
    padding-left:10px
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <img src="http://boxedinfinity.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Halo3.jpg" alt="Game Image" id="gameImage" />
    </div>
    <div id="second">
         <h2>Genre:</h2>
        <p>First Person Shooter</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Solution #4

using `inline-block`

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 0;/* fix for inline-block elements gaps*/
  border:1px solid red;    
}
#container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 16px /* fix for inline-block elements gaps*/
}
#container > div:first-child,
#container > div > img {
  width: 100px
}
#container > div > img {
  display: block
}
#container > #second > p {
  padding-left: 10px
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <img src="http://boxedinfinity.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Halo3.jpg" alt="Game Image" id="gameImage" />
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <h2>Genre:</h2>
    <p>First Person Shooter</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:**
You may want to take a look at some articles regarding floats, [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats) and [here](http://designshack.net/articles/css/everything-you-never-knew-about-css-floats/)

Comment: Thanks for the great post, I used solution #2!

Comment: @user1282637 Glad to help! solution #2 had a little bug i just fixed, if you wanna take a look again :)

Answer (score 1):

Your margin on #second must be as large as your image (100px) + the padding you want. Try with margin-left: 150px you will see.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the space well with giving `width` to each element. You can give width as `px` or in `%` . You can try this

```
#second {
    background-color: green;
    float:left;
    width:80%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The non-floating element actually takes the entire width of the frame.

```css
img {
    float: left;
    opacity: .75;
}
div {
    background: aqua;
    padding-left: 50px; /*nothing happens visually*/
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150" />
<div>Hello</div>
```

To fix it you could simply set `overflow:auto` on it.

```css
img {
    float: left;
    opacity: .75;
}
div {
    background: aqua;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150" />
<div>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve with the green box, but If you're just looking to keep things as they are, you need to make the `<p>` element and inline-block element so that it respects the floating `<img>` element and doesn't just wrap around it.

```
#second p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0za19kcx/