# Need help positioning in html

Tags: html, css

I want to put a list in between the embedded video and the picture and am unsure how to do so. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. If I did something incorrect asking this question please let me know.

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
       
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title> Yui </title>
 <style type="text/css">
  h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {color:green; text-align:center;}
     p {color:green;}
        a {color:green; text-align:center}
     hr {height:4px; background-color: black;width:100%;} 
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 
 <h1> Yui </h1>
 
 <hr>
 
 <h2> <a href="http://www.yui-lover.com/">Yui's Fanpage <a>
 &nbsp|
 <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yui_(singer)">Yui's Wiki </a>
 &nbsp|
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/YUI.net.International?fref=ts"> Yui's Facebook </a>
 </h2>
 
 <hr>
 
 <p>
 <a href="http://n-jinny.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/YUI1.jpg">
 <img style="float:right; border-color: transparent" src="http://n-jinny.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/YUI1.jpg" width="900" height="450" alt="Yui" > </a>
  YUI is a Japanese singer-songwriter and J-pop/J-rock artist, born March 26, 1987 in Fukuoka, Japan. She sings, plays the acoustic guitar, and writes her own songs. YUI has written a vast number of theme/tie-up songs for popular Japanese drama/film, anime and commercial productions. She is the second female in Japanese music history that has achieved a record of four consecutive No 1. Singles since J-pop star, Utada Hikaru. She is currently signed with Gr8! Records Label, a sublabel under Sony Music Entertainment (Japan).
    
 </p>
 
 <iframe width="560" height="315" 
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JmWf--kr4UQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
 </iframe>
 
 <ul style="list-style-type: circle">
       <li>Goodbye Days </li>
       <li>Again </li>
       <li>Life </li>
    </ul>

 
 <hr>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear what you really want to do. if by saying _list_ you mean this list: `<ul style="list-style-type: circle">` then you can simply move the `<ul>` block to the top of `<iframe>` which contains the youtube video. otherwise please elaborate on _I want to put a list in between the embedded video and the picture and am unsure how to do so_.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general idea of what you'd do:

**HTML**

```
<p class="clearfix">
  test
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</p>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
<iframe></iframe>
```

**CSS**

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
img {
  float: right;
}
```

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaMYoX?editors=110)

---

Explanation:

The `p` is a block level element, so it'll take up the whole width and the next element will be displayed underneath it. The `ul` is also a block level element, so it too will take up the whole width and the next element will be displayed underneath it. The `iframe` is an inline element, but since it's parent is block level, it'll be displayed underneath it.

If you run my code without the clearfix, it won't work. The `ul` won't be underneath the image. This is because the height of the `p` isn't reflecting the height of the `img` (which is inside the `p`). This is a well known problem, so I'll refer you to people who could explain it better than I could. Suffice it to say, using clearfix will give you your desired result.

- [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)
- [Why doesn't the height of a container element increase if it contains floated elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/why-doesnt-the-height-of-a-container-element-increase-if-it-contains-floated-el)

---

Tangential advice:

- Fix your indentation and style. Refer [here](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml) for a style guide. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help formatting in Stack Overflow.
- http://sscce.org/ is great advice on how to ask questions such that people could more easily help you, and so others would find your question useful. People often use [Code Pen's](http://codepen.io/) to demonstrate their SSCCEs.
- If you want to go a bit above and beyond, sketching out what you want things to look like and adding it as an image would be really useful. I use [Sketch](http://Sketch) for this, and [LiceCap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) to take screenshots and GIFs when appropriate. EDIT: your code snippet did a good job of visually showing what you want.
- I think http://learn.shayhowe.com/ is a great resource for HTML/CSS.