# CSS a tags doesn't line-up

Tags: html, css

The title might sound confusing, but I didn't know a better title.

I'm having trouble lining up my `nav` bar. 4 of the `a` tags ar on their place, the 5th is below the first.

Here is my code:

```
<nav>
    <a href='#'>1</a>
    <a href='#'>2</a>
    <a href='#'>3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Some simple math would make 5 * 20% = 100%. That fact, including the fact there is no `margin`, `padding`, `border` or whatever, makes me question whats going on.

Anyone who could help me with this one?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/23n76huL/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem with `display: inline-block;`. This property adds a nonbreaking space in between the content elements causing the overflow. To avoid this add `margin-left: -4px;` to the content. Optionally, you can also remove the margin from the first element and vertically align the content as shown below:

**Method 1:**

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
a:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href='#'>1</a>
    <a href='#'>2</a>
    <a href='#'>3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>
</nav>
```

**Reference:** [Fighting the space between inline-block elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

**Method 2:**

This one is a bit more awkward, but also works. Align the opening tag of each element on the same line as the closing tag of the previous element.

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href='#'>1</a><a href='#'>
    2</a><a href='#'>
    3</a><a href="#">
    4</a><a href="#">
    5</a>
</nav>
```

In this case the white space is removed without editing the margin of the elements. Optionally, you can leave the `vertical-align: top;` property in here as well.

**Method 3:**

The third and final method is using `float: left` on each of your anchor tags. This does come with some caveats that should be noted however. The most notable issue, is the cause of this content to fall outside the normal element box model flow (i.e. `width` and `height` of the parent element will be 0 and 0 respectively). To accomodate for this, you'll need to add a clear fix value as described in the link below:

```css
a {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<nav class="group">
    <a href='#'>1</a>
    <a href='#'>2</a>
    <a href='#'>3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>
</nav>
```

Assign the class `group` to the `<nav>` element to fix the floating issue described above.

**Reference:** [Force elements to self-clear its children](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Answer (score 0):

The whitespaces in your HTML are being registered and cause the overflow. Try adding `float: left` to your `a` style.

Comment: That solves one problem, but adds another. I have a background set to the `nav` and by adding a floot to the `a` it sets the `height` of the `nav` to `0px`.

Comment: @VellosFree If you choose the float route over the margin fix route, you'll need to apply a `clearfix` as described here...

Comment: @VellosFree, War10ck is correct. You can add a clearfix to your `nav` element by using `overflow: auto`

Comment: @MattO'Connell This would be a particular bad idea for clearing your floats. This would most ideally be done with a `clear:both;`.

Comment: @SteynvanEsveld, Why? Could you elaborate. Seems to work fine for me

Comment: @MattO'Connell, because height of floated element is undetermined http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/why-doesnt-the-height-of-a-container-element-increase-if-it-contains-floated-el

Comment: @MattO'Connell Because it's a little hacky CSS trick that happens to work but is not made for this. Clears are made for clearing floats and should be used that way imo. It's a couple of lines more CSS but it's much more logical.

Answer (score 0):

css change from 20 to 19:

```
width: 19%;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ca20mbtp/)

Comment: This will end up being `95%` in total, which is not always the `20px` difference. Sooner or later, this is going to give you unwanted results.