# Footer placing itself behind gallery

Tags: html, css

I got troubles placing my footer at the bottom on one page. It works fine on all pages, except for my gallery page.

The footer places itself behind the gallery images, while the content displays after the last image in the gallery.

In my structure the footer is placed after all the images in the gallery, but when I inspect the site, it seems like the div has no height.

Comment: Offhand it's probably a float clearing issue.

Comment: Probable duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/why-doesnt-the-height-of-a-container-element-increase-if-it-contains-floated-el

Comment: Thanks, I added a div before the footer and styled it with clear="both".

Answer (score 1):

Try add `float: left` to gallery and footer and then set also `width: 100%` for footer.

Comment: Definetly placed the footer content how it should be. The background color however is still messed up. But thanks for the input :)