# div inside a div 0 height

Tags: html, css

I created a div id="A" and div id="B" and placed the latter div inside div A. Div A has a background-color attribute, but the inside div shows up as its own separate div without the A's background-color. I thought a div within a div would take the attributes of parent div. Instead, div A shows up with 0 height on the browser. The divs below follow the same structure and are just named differently: 'AboutPictures'(A) and 'ya'(B)

```
<div id="AboutPictures">
    <div id="ya">
        <img style='border:5px solid #F00' src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/3ad1ef80a08560a7e5f6be2b31f13c2/tumblr_n5wto2Ukmf1txjmgjo1_1280.jpg">
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <figure>
            <figcaption>Hello I am Edward</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#AboutPictures {
    background-color: rgb(0,200,255);
    height:100%;
}
#ya{
    float:right;
}
#ya figure{
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there are different possibilities to solve this:

- you could add a `float: right / left;` to your outer div (#AboutPictures)
- or you could set it to `display: inline-block;`

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8j2zpfdg/

Another SO answer as reference: [How to make div not larger than its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/how-to-make-div-not-larger-than-its-contents)

Comment: cool, so when you add float to the outer div does how does it recognize there is content within it?

Comment: When using float on the outer div it behaves like an inline-block.

For a more detailed explanation check this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16568504/5663598)

That answer gives even more insights and possible solutions for your problem. Glad I could help you!

Answer (score 2):

Since your `#ya` div is floated, the parent div just sees empty content. You need to `clear` the `#AboutPictures` div, by applying the `clear: both` style. See: [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

Working example:

```
<div id="AboutPictures">
    <div id="ya">
        <img style='border:5px solid #F00' src="https://placehold.it/350x150">
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <figure>
            <figcaption>Hello I am Edward</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```