# Row height in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question regarding how Bootstrap works.

Suppose I have a row with two columns of class 'col-xs-6'. Now each of these columns have a float of left.

If my understanding is correct, a div containing float elements will have a height of zero.

Although, in this case, the row (div with a class of row) has some height (equal to the height of the containing columns). How does the row get that height?

Comment: dear, class raw & col-xs-6 get height automatically set with her inner content. if you set .row height with manually. the inner col-xs-6 have not effect.

Comment: it's not a learning platform, it's a problem solving platform.. ok dear?

Comment: How Does CSS Float Work ? check this post...http://stackoverflow.com/a/16568504/5086633

Comment: @yeppe Thank you! That answers my question. And to answer your previous comment, I have just begun learning. :)

Comment: @OmarFaruque Row height is not automatically set unless you use the clear property, it is set to zero. That was the point. Anyways, not it is resolved. :)