# css how to make columns auto fill background color to height 100%

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#right {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    right<br/> down
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to make the left column's `background-color` to fill the whole `div`. This should be the case regardless of the height of the `#right` column.

so far I have tried/added

```
display: flex;
height: 100%
flex 1;
```

To the `#left` style but it is not working.

This has to be a CSS only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox here. Demo:

```css
.container {
  /* become a flex-container */
  /* flex-items will be stretched vertically by default */
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#right {
  /* occupy remaining width */
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    right
    <br/> down
  </div>
</div>
```

Also you can use CSS Grid layout here. Demo:

```css
.container {
  /* become a grid-container */
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  
  /* first column should occupy 180px and second should occupy remaining width */
  -ms-grid-columns: 180px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 180px 1fr;
}

#left {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#right {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  
  /* specify column for IE/Edge explicitly */
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    right
    <br/> down
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @gilesrpa Consider upvoting if it helped you:)

Answer (score 1):

Need to understand why `#left` doesn't takes `height` of `100%` and that's because you have used `float:left` property in #left. So whenever float left is used on an element it by default changes it display to `inline-block` and that's the reason that you have to change display of your parent div to overcome this.

Here is below using flex,

```css
div{
  display:flex;
}
div #left {
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

div #right {
  flex:1;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    right<br/> down
  </div>
</div>
```

Read this to understand how [float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/why-doesnt-the-height-of-a-container-element-increase-if-it-contains-floated-el) works.

Comment: How does it differ from my answer?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Both ways are added i.e. using table and flex. And OP asked for flex. But I need others to understand why it didn't work i.e. height 100%. I need to add a flex code, it's same you have added a class I have used div. Just for that float point I need to add this code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-table {
  display: table;
}

#left {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#right {
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-table">
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    right<br/> down
  </div>
</div>
```

Something like table may help you in this case!!