# CSS HTML image next to the paragraph - background lost

Tags: html, css

I would like to place the image next to the paragraph. Unfortunately the background disappears.

My code looks like this:

```
    <figure class="fig">
       <label>
       <div class="order">23</div>
       <p>Suggested Location for RTD & Basement Box<span class="asterisk">&#42;</span></p>
       <img src="../images/basement_box.png" width="30%"></img>
       <div style="clear:both;"></div>
       </label>
       <br>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your answer">
       <br>
       </figure>

 label {
background-color: #E6EDF2;
padding: 5px;
}

 label img {
 display: inline;
 float:left;
 }
```

[image]

The image shows my problem.

I want the image next to the paragraph without losing the background.

If I put `float:left` or `float:right` image is placed quite well, but the background is rolled up to the paragraph only.

The `clear:both;` option doesn't work either, bringing back everything to the beginning.

How can I place my image, as shown in "good" example?

Comment: Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/why-doesnt-the-height-of-a-container-element-increase-if-it-contains-floated-el

Comment: try `p{display: inline-block}` and remove `label img`.

Comment: best option to handle this is, give overflow: hidden; to the parent of floated items, it will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you all for these hints

I solved it as you can see below.

Answer (score 0):

it's happen because u give your img element `display:inline`,that makes your image acted like a text,so it's move down,try:

```
img { display: block; position: absolute; right: 0; }
```

that's make your image one layer above your text

Answer (score -1):

Basing on the hints provided in the comments I've solved finally this issue.

I used the `overflow:hidden` feature and placed `clear:both;` at the bottom of my label

```
<figure class="fig">
<label>
<img src="../images/basement_box.png" width="30%"></img>
<div class="order">23</div>
<p>Suggested Location for RTD & Basement Box<span class="asterisk">&#42; 
</span></p>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</label>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your answer">
<br>
</figure>
```

And CSS

```
 label img {
 float:right;
 overflow: hidden;
 }
```